# Vue.js Data binding issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to bind data in my userDetails array through post request but i did not get the data , i had tried all the possible solution given in stackoverflow and also in vue.js docs but nothing helps me here is my code.

```
ND.user_list = new Vue({
el: '#user_list',
data: {
  userDetails: []
},
mounted: function () {
  $.post(ND.routes['users.get'], [], function(data) {
    //console,log(data);
    this.$set(this, 'userDetails', data);
    //this.usersDetails = data;

  }.bind(this), 'json');
  //onsole.log(this.userDetailsdata);
}


});
```

i am getting data in console log in mounted function but not getting in userDetails array declare in data. here is my view code

```
<div class="ui grid container" id="user_list">
```

```
  <table class="ui celled padded table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6">Top Users</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="ui center aligned">#</th>
        <th class="ui center aligned">Name </th>
        <th class="ui center aligned">Email </th>
        <th class="ui center aligned">User Type</th>
        <th class="ui center aligned">Action </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% verbatim %}
    <tr v-for="user in userDetails">
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="single line">{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td class="ui center aligned "></td>
      <td class="ui center aligned "></td>
      <td class="ui center aligned ">
      <select class="ui dropdown">
        <option value=" ">Action </option>
        <option value="1">Edit</option>
        <option value="0">Delete</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
          {% endverbatim %}


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you already know if the problem is with fetching data or with passing it to Vue?

Comment: yes the problem is passing it to vue

Comment: I think you setting data is incorrect . It should be `Vue.set(object, key, value)`

Comment: i have already tried this but it won't helps me

Comment: Vue.set(this, 'userDetails', data); 
same result can't get data

Comment: No ! You should try like this `this.set(this.userDetails, 1, data)`

Comment: sorry but it also can't work , i am totally stucked

Comment: I see your are using inside post function ,so your `this` will be not Vue property . So declare `this` before post function and called that variable inside

Comment: mounted: function () {
      var self = this;
      $.post(ND.routes['users.get'], [], function(data) {
        //console,log(data);
        self.$set(self.userDetails, 1, data)
        //this.users.$set('data is here');
        
      }.bind(self), 'json');
      console.log(self.userDetails);
    }

Comment: also does not work

Comment: getting result in console.log but data no assigning

Comment: @DavidJorHpan can you help me more ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170768/discussion-between-numair-and-david-jorhpan).

Comment: That is because `this` in your post function callback does not refer to the Vue instance. Create a proxy for it within the mounted callback, e.g. `var that = this`, and in your post callback use `that.userDetails = ...` instead.

Comment: Any specific reason to not use [Single File Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)? It seems like it would be cleaner, though of course requires annoying compilation. I'd try adding more vue markup, e.g. plain `{{ userDetails }}` before the whole table (remember about `{% verbatim %}`), or so. Also, take a look at `ND.user_list` in the console, is `ND.user_list.userDetails` updated? It seems to me like the problem is strictly in rendering.

Comment: yes the problem is with rendering and ND.user_list.userDetails are bind correctly but it not render in an array

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in the callback fo `$.post()` does not refer to the VueJS instance. This means that `this.userDetails` actually will return undefined within the callback. What you can do is to create a proxy for the VueJS instance as such:

```
ND.user_list = new Vue({
  el: '#user_list',
  data: {
    userDetails: []
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // Proxy `this`
    var that = this;

    $.post(ND.routes['users.get'], [], function(data) {

      // `that` will refer to VueJS instance
      that.userDetails = data;

    }, 'json');
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems like the `.bind()` in original code should handle that just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this.$set wrong: it should only be used when you got an object in the data object and want to add properties to that object that wasn't there before, or if you want to change indexes of the array. Then first argument should not be the vue object, but the data object (i.e. the object or array in the data object). See documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html or https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set.

Instead of: `this.$set(this, 'userDetails', data);` you should just do `this.userDetails = data;`. Have you tried this? Also, if you change elements in the array, then you should use Vue.set or splice, but read the documentation carefully before you use it.